# How can I specify 'failureReason' in failure message of SageMaker Async Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-sagemaker

I have set up my SageMaker endpoint using Async Endpoint and provided SNS Topic ARN for the SuccessTopic and ErrorTopic parameters. I am receiving success and failure messages from these SNS Topics without error but I want the failure messages to be more verbose. The failure message looks like this:

```json
{
    "awsRegion": "...",
    "eventTime": "...",
    "receivedTime": "...",
    "invocationStatus": "Failed",
    "failureReason": "ClientError: Received server error (500) from model. See the SageMaker Endpoint logs in your account for more information.",
    "requestParameters": {
        "endpointName": ...,
        "inputLocation": ...
    },
    "inferenceId": "...",
    "eventVersion": "1.0",
    "eventSource": "aws:sagemaker",
    "eventName": "InferenceResult"
}
```

There might be different reasons for the service to throw error such as CUDA OOM errors or an assertion error that I have thrown. I would love to see this information from the SNS message. However, the only way to see any additional information for the error is to see the SageMaker Endpoint logs.

Each time I receive an error from sagemaker service, The failureReason is the same. Is there a way to specify `failureReason` parameter in this message?

I have tried adding Exception messages to all exceptions that I raised in the code but the message never changed. I have no access to SNS topic during the execution. I have created an SNS client using boto3 and sent a notification before raising any assertion error but I don't know any way to stop executing the sagemaker execution without throwing an error, which sends another failure message automatically.

Comment: Tuna Meral - did you find any solution for this question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.